# How can I get the WorkerRole IP while using Azure emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-emulator

How can I get the WorkerRole IP while using Azure emulator ?
Im using Azure SDK 2.7.

I tried to iterate through RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance endpoints in my worker's role OnStart method, but no endpoint was found. (As far I know, the Azure Emulator is unable to read the definded enpoints :( )

Ok... If im not able to read the definded endpoints, so it would be still ok for me the get the autoassigned ones. So I open my emulator, go to the service details and... I got only the IP for my web role...

Did anyone have a similar problem before ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an "Input Endpoint".

[image]

so now I have an IP address displayed under my emulator

[image]